# Create new column from subsets with original dataframe row association

Tags: r

I need to make a new column called 'night' in a dataframe called 'test'.  I have many 1000s rows of measurements associated with times in recording periods over multiple nights.  One column has the date, another the time of recording.  Since the recording is overnight, there are two dates associated with each night's recording - that before midnight (date1), and that after (date2).  My goal is one new column with a single date derived from date1. I want to avoid an IF ELSE approach because it takes too long - SUBSETs seems pretty quick.  I was almost successful with that below, but when I RBIND to produce a new vector, I lose the original row number association to the dataframe 'test'.  So in 'test2' when I cross reference values on 'night', they do not match the correct 'date' because RBIND discards the original row number and does not interleave the subsets.   Thanks for your trouble.

dataframe="test"

```
    measure1    measure2    date        time    <desired new col=night>  
1   2.3         4.5         2013-12-01  1800.00     2013-12-01  
2   2.2         4.4         2013-12-01  2353.45     2013-12-01  
3   2.1         4.2         2013-12-02  0315.56     2013-12-01  
4   2.6         4.4         2013-12-02  1903.23     2013-12-02      
5   2.2         4.7         2013-12-03  0553.12     2013-12-02  
etc


AA<-test[test$date=="2013-12-01", ]
WW <- subset(AA, time>180000 & time<235959, select=date) 
BB<-test[test$date=="2013-12-02", ]
XX <- subset(BB, time>=0 & time<070000, select=date)
ZZ1 <- replace(XX, "2013-12-02", "2013-12-01")
#or else
KK1 <-rbind(WW, XX)

AA<-test[test$date=="2013-12-02", ]
WW <- subset(AA, time>180000 & time<235959, select=date) 
BB<-test[test$date=="2013-12-03", ]
XX <- subset(BB, time>=0 & time<070000, select=date)
ZZ2 <- replace(XX, "2013-12-03", "2013-12-02")
#or else
KK2 <-rbind(WW, XX)

...
#repeated for each date of interest

FF<- rbind(KK1, KK2, ...)
#or else
FF<- rbind(ZZ1, ZZ2, ...)

colnames(FF) <-'night'
test2 <- data.frame(cbind(test, FF))
```

Comment: You say "two dates associated..." yet you assigned 12-01 to three rows. What are your exact criteria for grouping tests into a given day?  --- Meanwhile, my guess is that if, e.g. any test prior to noon "belongs" to the previous day, you can create your "night" values by subtracting 11hrs,59 minutes from "time" , concatenating these altered"times" with the "date" values, and returning the year/month/day of the result.

Comment: Yes, I did not explain in detail, just assumed the example code would explain.  The data are recorded at night, so between 1800 hours and 0700 hours the next day.  Thanks Carl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly...before 07 in the morning (i.e. time < 700, with your formatting), subtract 1 from current date:

```
test$date <- as.Date(test$date)

test$night <- test$date - 1 * (test$time < 700)

test
#   measure1 measure2       date    time      night
# 1      2.3      4.5 2013-12-01 1800.00 2013-12-01
# 2      2.2      4.4 2013-12-01 2353.45 2013-12-01
# 3      2.1      4.2 2013-12-02  315.56 2013-12-01
# 4      2.6      4.4 2013-12-02 1903.23 2013-12-02
# 5      2.2      4.7 2013-12-03  553.12 2013-12-02
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik, I thought it would be something this simple. I will try this and report back to the site.

Comment: Worked brilliantly on my large dataset.  Thank you so much.  Makes some of my other code easier as well.